# SQLite inner join limit 1

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables `objectTable` and `photo_table`. Here's sample data from `objectTable`

```
ID  TEXT
1   Kaunas
2   Vilnius
3   Palanga
4   Prienai
```

and here's data from `photo_table`

```
OBJECT_ID PHOTO_ID NAME
1          7       tets7.jpg
1          8       tets8.jpg
1          9       tets9.jpg
1          10      tets10.jpg
1          11      tets11.jpg
2          3       tets3.jpg
2          2       tets2.jpg
3          1       tets1.jpg
3          5       tets5.jpg
4          6       tets6.jpg
4          7       tets7.jpg
4          8       tets8.jpg
```

So as you can see one object can have many pictuure. I need to get first picture of evety object (My output should be)

```
ID TEXT   NAME
1 Kaunas  tets7.jpg
2 Vilnius tets3.jpg
3 Palanga tets1.jpg
4 Prienai tets6.jpg
```

And here's my query:

```
select * 
from objectTable 
inner join photo_table 
   on photo_table.OBJECT_ID = (select OBJECT_ID 
                               from photo_table 
                               where photo_table.OBJECT_ID = objectTable.ID 
                               order by photo_table.OBJECT_ID desc 
                               limit 1).
```

However I try to figure almost 3 hours why this query don't work. What I'm missing? Is my logic correct?

Comment: Your sample output doesn't make sense.  You say you want to get the first picture of every object, but what makes a picture "first?"  For the second result in your sample output, the photos would have had to be ordered in a reverse order than the others which are sorted as ascending.  Are you sure 'tets3.jpg' isn't supposed to be 'tets2.jpg'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.NAME
FROM objectTable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT OBJECT_ID, MIN(PHOTO_ID) AS PHOTO_ID
   FROM photo_table
   GROUP BY OBJECT_ID
) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN photo_table AS t3 ON t3.OBJECT_ID = t2.OBJECT_ID AND
                                t3.PHOTO_ID = t2.PHOTO_ID
```

The trick is to use a derived table that selects the `PHOTO_ID` value per `OBJECT_ID`. This value is used in an additional join to `photo_table`, so as to select the required `NAME` value.

Comment: It works but honestly I don't understand it, can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4):

To me Following your code I'll change the DESC for ASC and the ID column that orders it, to get the photo with the lowest ID

```
select * 
from objectTable 
inner join photo_table 
   on photo_table.OBJECT_ID = (select OBJECT_ID 
                               from photo_table 
                               where photo_table.OBJECT_ID = objectTable.ID 
                               order by photo_table.PHOTO_ID ASC
                               limit 1).
```